# How to modify Content of Control (create new content and restore old content back later) C#?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I need to modify my `XAML` elements by code. I need to replace original `content` with new `content` inside `ScrollViewer` "XAML_ScrollViewer". Simple example of `XAML` code.

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="XAML_ScrollViewer">
    <ListView x:Name="XAML_ListView">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:SomeInformation">
                <Grid>

                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</ScrollViewer>
```

To do this I use following code. Everything is so far well. New `content` appears as it should to do.

C#

```
//SourceElementParent = XAML_ScrollViewer

//GET PRESENT CONTENT
FrameworkElement ControlOldContent = (SourceElementParent as ContentPresenter).Content as FrameworkElement;
//CREATE NEW GRID
Grid NewParentGrid = new Grid();
//USE NEW GRID AS CONTENT
(SourceElementParent as ContentPresenter).Content = NewParentGrid;
//ADD SOME ELEMENT 01
NewParentGrid.Children.Add(XAMLElement_01);
//ADD SOME ELEMENT 02
NewParentGrid.Children.Add(XAMLElement_02);
//ADD OLD CONTENTS INTO A NEW GRID
NewParentGrid.Children.Add(ControlOldContent );
```

But when I need to restore the original `content` I cannot do it. The following code works BUT created `Grid` inside `ScrollViewer` must remain.

C#

```
//CLEAR ALL CHILDREN OF THE GRID
((SourceElementParent  as ContentPresenter).Content as Grid).Children.Clear();
//ADD OLD CONTENT TO THE GRID
((SourceElementParent  as ContentPresenter).Content as Grid).Children.Add(ControlOldContent);
```

Because I want to restore the control `ScrollViewer` to the old state (`content` as it was before any modify) I also need to rid of the `Grid` I created earlier. But if I do so I get `exception` if I resize window size by mouse. If I don't resize all looks good.

I get the following exception:

e = {Windows.UI.Xaml.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs} 
Exception =  {"Invalid pointer\r\n\r\nInvalid pointer\r\n"}

I tried to use following code to restore `contents` but it fails.

C#

```
//CLEAR ALL CHILDREN OF GRID
((SourceElementParent  as ContentPresenter).Content as Grid).Children.Clear();
//ADD ORIGINAL CONTENT
(SourceElementParent  as ContentPresenter).Content = ControlOldContent;
```

So, any good hints how to solve this problem?

Comment: You're on a very wrong track. Except for rare scenarios, you should not need to access your UI elements in the code-behind. Modifying/restoring content is part of application logic and should happen at VM level. The UI should adjust itself automatically to reflect VM changes. Use `DataTemplate`s and `DataTemplateSelector`s to get more control over the UI customization. What you're doing is against the spirit of MVVM.

Comment: My example was quite simplify and I didn't explain the reason why I need to do this. Usually there are not too many reasons to fork UI elements in the code behind. But I'm making a routines to create and remove shadows behind the UI elements. Idea is like this: "CreateShadow (FrameworkElement,  params)" , "ShowShadow (FrameworkElement)", "HideShadow (FrameworkElement), "RemoveShadow (FrameworkElement)". This is why I need to create a Grid for Shadow, Visual etc. To make all these needed changes in XAML by hand is just nightmare. Anyway, I founded a light brain fart in my code and all is fixed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found a working solution finally. `Content` must restore as new `ScrollContentPresenter`. So the `ContentPresenter` type must be exactly correct and I didn't realize this before.

```
//CLEAR ALL CHILDREN OF GRID
((SourceElementParent  as ContentPresenter).Content as Grid).Children.Clear();
//RESTORE SCROLLVIEWER CONTENT.
(SourceElementParent as ScrollContentPresenter).Content = new ScrollContentPresenter() { Content = ControlOldContent };
```